# Need help with notation. Is this lower dot an operation?

Tags: notation, lie-algebras

I'm working through *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory* by *Humphreys*, and I came across this notation $L.v$ as you can see in the picture. I cannot find where it's first introduced, or maybe it's assumed known.

Please help me, it's difficult to continue without knowing what this means.

[image]

Comment: The elements of $L$ are matrices, if you want. So $L.v=\{Av\mid A\in L\}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you! Now I can stop tearing my hair and read on.